# Misplaced Excel output's second column value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Below is my program where I am trying to update the Birds column, but the value (e.g. "duck") is not updated after the "parrot" value. I want the output as below.

Program:

```
package config;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Writing 
{
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception
    {
        FileInputStream f1=new FileInputStream("D://XL4.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook w1=new XSSFWorkbook(f1);
        XSSFSheet s1=w1.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFCell c = null;
        XSSFRow r = null;
        int rows=s1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        for(int i=0;i<=rows;i++)
        {
            r = s1.getRow(i); 
            if(r == null)
            {
                s1.createRow((short) (i)).createCell(1).setCellValue("Duck");
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream f2=new FileOutputStream("D://XL4.xlsx");
        w1.write(f2);
        f2.close();
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
Animals     Birds
Elephant    Parrot
Lion        Duck
Tiger   
Deer    
Cow
```

Actual result:

```
Animals     Birds
Elephant    Parrot
Lion    
Tiger   
Deer    
Cow 
            Duck
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Before placing "Duck" in the list, perhaps check if the cell above is empty, and if so, move up a cell, and check the one above that, and if empty, move up, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am unable to get the expected result even after checking the cell is null/empty before updating the value(ex:Duck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(r == null)
```

is the culprit here. When you are in 3rd row **r = s1.getRow(i)** will not be null. So, call will not come inside the condition block.

Change the condition to row is not null and second cell is null - create new cell and assign value "Duck" here.

Comment: I have updated the below condition and observed that the duck value is overriding the remaining values.
 if(r != null && r.getCell(1)==null)
 {
  s1.createRow((short) (i)).createCell(1).setCellValue("Duck");
 }

Comment: Condition's are fine now. But, don't create new row again because it already exists. Just create new cell and assign the value

**r.createCell(1).setCellValue("Duck");**

Comment: Thanks for the support guys.I found the below program after my analysis and your support.

Answer (score -1):

```
Thanks for the support.I found the below program after my analysis.

package config;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Writing1 
{
@Test
    public void test() throws Exception
    {
FileInputStream f1=new FileInputStream("D://XL5.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook w1=new XSSFWorkbook(f1);
XSSFSheet s1=w1.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFCell c = null;
XSSFRow r = null;
int count=0;
int rows=s1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
for(int p=0;p<rows;p++)
{
     r = s1.getRow(p);
     if(r.getCell(1)!=null)
         count++;

}
System.out.println(count);

for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
{
    r = s1.getRow(i); 
    if(r!= null&&r.getCell(1)==null)
    {
        s1.getRow((short) (i)).createCell(1).setCellValue("Duck");
    }
    else if(r==null)
        s1.createRow(i).createCell(1).setCellValue("Duck");
}
FileOutputStream f2=new FileOutputStream("D://XL5.xlsx");
w1.write(f2);
f2.close();
        }

}
```